# Download all data in the list provided by sentinelhub (python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to download all the data queried at once. My code as follows:

```
from sentinelhub import AwsProductRequest, AwsTileRequest, AwsTile, BBox, CRS
import sentinelhub

betsiboka_coords_wgs84 = [38.788605,35.781057,39.314575,36.180008]
bbox = BBox(bbox=betsiboka_coords_wgs84, crs=CRS.WGS84)
date= '2016-09-05',('2018-03-08')
for i in data:
    print(i['properties']['title'])
```

This code  returns :
S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_EPAE_20180307T093658_A014132_T37SBD_N02.06
S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_EPAE_20180307T093658_A014132_T36SYH_N02.06
S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_EPAE_20180307T093658_A014132_T36SYJ_N02.06
S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_EPAE_20180307T093658_A014132_T37SBC_N02.06
S2B_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_MPS__20180305T103142_A005195_T36SYH_N02.06

After it returns this list of tile_id's, I use the code to extract tile-`name and date of a single tile_id (For example: **S2B_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_MPS__20170906T122033_A002621_T36STA_N02.05):**

```
tile_id ='S2B_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_MPS__20170906T122033_A002621_T36STA_N02.05'
tile_name, time, aws_index = AwsTile.tile_id_to_tile(tile_id)
tile_name, time, aws_index
```

This returns:
('36STA', '2017-9-6', 0)

The last bit of code tells what bands should be downloaded,the directory where they should be dowloaded and so on:

```
bands = ['B02','B03','B04']
metafiles = [ 'preview']

data_folder = './ChangeDetection'

request = AwsTileRequest(tile=tile_name, time=time, aws_index=aws_index,
                         bands=bands, metafiles=metafiles, data_folder=data_folder)
request.save_data()
```

So in order to download several images I have to copy and paste Tile_id each time. My question is: How could I write a code so it picks up one Tile_id downloads and then goes to second Tile_id and downloads it as well. And keeps downloading till the list is finished.
Regards,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question specifically, you need to get a list of all the tiles that meet your parameters using the Sentinelhub Web Feature Service. Then you can pass that list through an iterator, extracting the input information for the tile/product request them implementing it.

This is the code I have, its not very pretty but it does the trick. Note that it is currently set to download in .SAFE mode, and also that if you are not working in an AWS environment you will need to pass in your AWS Security Credentials.

```
from sentinelhub import WebFeatureService, BBox, CRS, AwsProductRequest, AwsTile, DataSource, AwsTileRequest

# config for sentinelhub WFS requests
INSTANCE_ID = 'YOUR INSTANCE HERE' 

#boundslist format eg = [101.429, 0.4629, 101.64, 0.6737]
#searchdates format eg =('2018-08-01T00:00:00', '2018-08-31T23:59:59')
#cloudmax format eg = 0.25

def batchdownloader(boundslist,searchdates,cloudmax,downloadfolder,):
    search_bbox = BBox(bbox = boundslist, crs=CRS.WGS84)
    search_time_interval = searchdates
    wfs_iterator = WebFeatureService(search_bbox, search_time_interval,
                                 data_source=DataSource.SENTINEL2_L1C,
                                 maxcc=cloudmax, instance_id=INSTANCE_ID)


    outinfo=wfs_iterator.get_tiles()
    print('The tool will download',len(outinfo), 'images.')
    for i in outinfo:
        tilename = i[0]
        tiledate = i[1]
        tileindex = i[2]
        productid=(AwsTile(tile_name=tilename, time=tiledate, aws_index=tileindex, data_source=DataSource.SENTINEL2_L1C).get_product_id())
        print (productid)

        #Uncomment the below code if you want to download the whole product
        #product_request = AwsProductRequest(product_id=productid, data_folder=downloadfolder, safe_format=True)
        #product_request.save_data()
        #print (productid, '.SAFE folder for this image has been downloaded to', downloadfolder, )

        #uncomment the below code if you want to download just the tiles
        #tile_request = AwsTileRequest(tile=tilename, time=tiledate, aws_index=tileindex, data_folder=downloadfolder, safe_format=True)
        #tile_request.save_data()
        #print (productid, 'Tiles for this image have been downloaded to', downloadfolder)
        i =+1
    print('Completed downloads.')


batchdownloader([110.3055, -1.0574, 110.4125, -0.87],('2018-06-15T00:00:00', '2018-06-30T23:59:59'), 0.4, r'C:\YOURFOLDER')
```